# not working in plot: sharex=True, sharey=True

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

`sharex=True` and `sharey=True` is not working in below code:

```
   fig, ax = plot.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(5, 5))
   for i in range(1,16):

         plot.subplot(4,4,i)

         im=plot.contourf(xlon[:],xlat[:],diffrain[i,:,:])

    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.825)
    cax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.06, 0.035, 0.91])
   fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
 plot.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to decide if you create the axes via `subplot` or `subplots` - bot not both. For this simple case, `subplots` should work just fine.

```
fig, axes = plot.subplots(4,4, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(5, 5))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
     im=ax.contourf(xlon[:],xlat[:],diffrain[i,:,:])

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.825)
cax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.06, 0.035, 0.91])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plot.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Importance it work

Comment: can u tell me in above code what I am doing wrong in color line:  fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax): ...i want one colorbar for all subplots but I am getting wrong ,the range of colorabr is only last plot value.

Comment: Yes, because they *are* different. You may plot all images with the same color normalization, then you can plot a colorbar for just any of them.

Comment: sorry unable to understand

Comment: I did normalization but still, the range of colobar is showing for last plot range only....